# How to align the contents of the login form horizontally

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-forms

I have made a login form in which the contents are aligned vertically. What should I do to arrange it horizontally  just like the facebook login page is?

login.html

```
<div class="login-form">
        <form method="POST" class="post-form"> 
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="text-center">Log in</h2>
            <div class="form-group">  
                {{ form | crispy }}
                <div id='form-errors'>{{ form_errors }}</div>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <label class="pull-left checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                <a href="#" class="pull-right">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>  
        </form>
        <p class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Create an Account</a></p>
    </div>
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "password") 
        labels = {
            'username': 'Username',
            'password': 'Password'
        }
```

And here is my CSS file login_style.css

```
.login-form {
    width: 340px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.login-form form {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 30px;
}
.login-form h2 {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
.form-control, .btn {
    min-height: 38px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.btn {        
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Contents i.e the `username` and the `password` text fields or blocks are aligned vertically but I want to align them horizontally at the top, rather than vertically. How should I do that? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What should I do to arrange it horizontally just like the facebook login page is?

```
.login-form {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Contents i.e the username and the password text fields

```
<div class="form-group centered">  
    {{ form | crispy }}
     <div id='form-errors'>{{ form_errors }}</div>
</div>

.login-form .centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_align.asp

Comment: I tried what you shared @AgathoSAreS but the form is same as it was earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to put in class of form form-inline due to I watched that you are using bootstrap and you need to add this class. I add a example. [Example w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h)